# How to see files and folders available for download?

Tags: browser

I have a link to a website which gives me 403 forbidden error. I know that at that link there are further directories that contain files that are open to the public. Is it possible to see such directories/files without having a direct link to the file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and that's likely deliberate.  Web servers like IIS can be configured either to allow or to disallow directory browsing.  It's apparently been turned off on that website.

Comment: In fairness... it may not be a deliberate choice, as it's off by default. It could just as easily be they haven't bothered to turn it on.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn  Yes, correct.  I should have made that clear.  Thanks for pointing that out.